# Error on add function

Tags: cakephp

In my controller I have add($id = null) function. If iput add/43 it works. But if any validation failure It reloads without add/43. (after showing error message).
What to do?..  Version 1.3
**Controller :**

```
    function add($id = null) {    
if (!empty($this->data)) {     
              $this->ConsultingDet->create();   
      if ($this->ConsultingDet->save($this->data)) {  
          $this->Session->setFlash('The consulting det has been saved', true);  
          $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'patients', 'action' => 'home'));  
      } else {  
          $this->Session->setFlash('The consulting det could not be saved. Please,     try   again.', true);  
      }  
  }  
  if (is_null($id)) {  
      $this->set('id', 0);  
  }
```

}
**add.ctp :**

```
<div class="consultingDets form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('ConsultingDet');?>  
<fieldset> 
    <div class="sub1">
        <?php

        echo $this->Form->input('patient_id', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $patient['Patient']['id'])); 
        if ($id>0)       //This (id) brings out error on redirection
            echo $this->Form->input('id',array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $id));
            echo $this->Form->input('temperature');
        ?>            
    </div>         
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit', true)); ?>
```

Comment: because you will render the view add? If validation is false you can redirect to the referrer.

Comment: Maybe its because you dont set the id (by the way, its very rare trying to add an object that hasnt been created because of the validation...)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create(null, array('url' => 
            array('controller' => 'consultingdets', 'action' => 'add', $id))); ?>
//<form action="consultingdets/add/43"
```

basically pass the `id` you need as a param to the form. that way when you submit and validation fails, cake redirects to the correct URL (i.e. with the id you need as a param)

Your controller name may differ.

Comment: Still error is coming. form action="consultingdets/add/43" the form already shows like this when viewing source page (before using your answer).

Comment: What the problem is when redirecting (after validation failure) if ($id>0){} -in add.ctp- here showing  'undefined variable'

Comment: @alexkd this will address your question.

Comment: `$this->set('id', $id)` in your add function. You forgot to pass the id to your view when the id is not null

Comment: When I added set('id',$id) things become success, thanks...But why on setFlash the id is become blank after saving failure?.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function add($id = null) {    
   if (!empty($this->data)) {     
              $this->ConsultingDet->create();   
      if ($this->ConsultingDet->save($this->data)) {  
          $this->Session->setFlash('The consulting det has been saved', true);  
          $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'patients', 'action' => 'home'));  
      } else {  
          $this->Session->setFlash('The consulting det could not be saved. Please,   try   again.', true);  
          //redirect to referrer page
          $this->redirect($this->referer());           
      }  
  }  
  if (is_null($id)) {  
      $this->set('id', 0);  
  }
```

Comment: In this case FLash message is coming but the validation message is not appearing.

Comment: sorry, redirect is not the way to go. :)